# ManagedObjectContext within CoreDataStack is returned nil after unwrapping

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to get a firm grip on Core Data and for the most part everything makes since, especially with child/parent contexts and fetch result controller. However I'm sort of stuck on the CoreDataStack. I'm trying to call the attribute 'context' in the rest of the program. I can print the context in my first view but it doesn't seem to be persisting throughout the app via the navigation bar.

This is CoreDataStack.swift

```
//exablishes the directory to be used for the stack in SQLite fashion
private lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

//establishes the managed context by which managed objects interact in reading and writing
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.psc
    return managedObjectContext
}()

//establishes the coordinator that connects the managed context with the persistent store
private lazy var psc: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = { let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(
    managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.modelName)

    do {
        let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true]

        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType( NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options) //establishes the actual persistent store
    } catch {
        print("Error adding persistent store.")
    }
    return coordinator
}()
//establishes the object model that interacts with the GUI object data model
private lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(self.modelName, withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

And this is the relevant section in AppDelegate.Swift

```
    let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let listViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! ViewController
    listViewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really solve your problem, but I provide an alternate solution. I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided. It would be helpful to see how you later try to get the `CoreDataStack` in other view controllers, and why you think it's not persisting.

---

I usually make my `CoreDataStack` class just a collection of static methods and variables.

Replace `lazy` with `static` (all static vars are automatically lazy) for all of the variables on your `CoreDataStack`. Then, anywhere in your app you want to use your context:

```
let ctx = CoreDataStack.context;
```

Comment: I like it. Simplistic and efficient

Comment: it's also throwing errors for cases where I use "self.___". Should I simply remove all the instances of self as well?

Comment: @ggworean Yup! `self` is now not used since all of the methods and vars in `CoreDataStack` are static. They are class variables now instead of instance variables. You no longer instantiate `CoreDataStack`, you instead use it directly.

Comment: I'm getting a problem with how I make the saveContext() function. I think the weak connection the new contact object has to its child context is causing problems for the parent context properly saving it.

Comment: @ggworean Can you add related code to your question?